# Estimations skewness coefficients

Tags: python, pandas

My set contain categorical and numerical values. So I am try to estimate skewness coefficients only for numerical values in my data set. In order to do that I wrote this line of code

```
dataset_num = dataset.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64'])
```

But now I want to see what is skewness coefficients for each 8-variables which is selected by code above.I try with this line of code but I this dont work properly.

```
print("Skewness: %f" % dataset_num.skew())
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and estimate skewness for each 8-variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset_num.skew()` return a `pandas.core.series.Series` hence you cant use `%f` , you can try print the whole series

```
print("Skewness: \n", dataset_num.skew())
```

if you want better looking print with key value pairs you can do the following:

```
print("Skewness: \n", list(zip(dataset_num.skew().index,dataset_num.skew().values)))
```